# Nothing happens after clicking submit button (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a form to register new users in my rails app, I used the inspect params method to see what is it sending in the form but when I click the submit button nothing happens, looking up for solutions I found nothing helpful and I don't know what to do

**register.html.erb** in views/register/register.html.erb

```
    <%= form_with model: @client, url: clients_path do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">*Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
               <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %>
            </div>

            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">*Last name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <%= f.text_field :last_name, class:"form-control"%>
                </div>
       </div>

      <!-- Buttons -->
          <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                      <%= f.submit "Continue", class:"btn btn-primary btn-sm"%>
                      <%= f.submit "Cancel", class:"btn btn-primary btn-sm"%>
                   </div>
               </div>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  root to: "mainpages#index"

  get '/mainpages', controller: 'mainpages', action: 'index'
  get '/register', controller: 'register', action: 'register'

  resources :clients
```

**clients_controller.rb**

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    render plain: params[:client].inspect
  end    
end
```

**client.rb** (model)

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`remote` attribute of `form_with` is `true` by default. Therefore, nothing happens after clicking submit. You need to set `remote` to `false`:

```
<%= form_with model: @client, url: clients_path, remote: false do |f| %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have the same problem though

Comment: okay, i could solve the problem changing form_with for form_for

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're missing is an instance of the class `Client` which you can solve it in two ways:

1. In your `register controller`, create the instance of the `Client` class, like this:

```
class RegisterController < ApplicationController
  def register
    @client = Client.new
  end
end
```

OR

2. In your form:

```
<%= form_with model: Client.new do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Also, keep in mind, in your `clients_controller`, you need to save the new object/record:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)

    if @client.save
      redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new  #or redirect somewhere else
    end
  end

  private

  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:name, :last_name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `form_with` sets `data-remote` to "true", to render something else after submission. Try and set `local` to "true":

```
<%= form_with model: @client, url: clients_path, local: true do |f| %>
  
   ..

<% end %>
```